# sup and inf when even/odd subsequences converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, supremum-and-infimum

I need help finding **sup** and **inf** of the following sequence, **and determine whether the sequence has a maximum or a minimum**.

$$\bigg\{ \left(1+ \frac{(-1)^n}{2n} \right)^n \bigg\}^\infty_{n=1}$$

The subsequence for even n converges, I think:

$$\bigg\{ \left(1+ \frac{1}{2k} \right)^k \bigg\}^\infty_{k=2} \quad k = 2n$$
$$\bigg\{ \sqrt{\left(1+ \frac{1}{2k} \right)^{2k}} \bigg\}^\infty_{k=2p}$$
to $\sqrt{e}$. Similliar for the odd:
$$    \bigg\{ \left[\left(1+ (\frac{1}{-2p} )\right)^{-2p}\right]^{-1/2} \bigg\}^\infty_{p=2n-1} \to e^{-1/2}= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e}} \quad \text{when p}\to\infty$$

However, I don't really know what this says. Can I apply Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem? Is the original sequence equal to the two subsequences? As you can tell I need some guidance. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just look at the odd terms; are they approaching $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$ from below or from above?  What about the even terms approaching $\sqrt{e}$?

Comment: Keep in mind the distinction between sup and maximum, and between inf and minimum.

Comment: @Surb It's the only thing theorem we've done in my course regarding subsequences. Yes sure but does the original sequence reach those values?

Comment: @3ll: Consider whether the terms in the sequences are rational or irrational.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes I know and that's what I find difficult here. And thank you for the advice

Comment: You find the distinction between inf and sup, and min and max difficult?  Or you find determining rational/irrational of the terms difficult?

Comment: @BrianTung I meant mix and min, I don't know where to start. But I'm not sure what irrational/rational terms will tell me too

Comment: Is $e$ rational or irrational?  What about the terms?

Comment: @BrianTung oh your right! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** The even subsequence is strictly increasing and convergent to $\sqrt{e}$. The odd subsequence is strictly increasing and convergent to $1/\sqrt{e}$.

Moreover the term for $n=1$ is equal to $1/2$, and the term for $n=2$ is equal to $25/16$.

With all these informations, you should be able to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! But I still feel like I can't motivate this enough. Is this always the case for subsequences? Even if I'm pretty sure I've found the answer feel I don't have something to back it up

Comment: Hi again, are you sure the odd subsequence is strictly decreasing..?

Comment: Edited, sorry ;)